# upgrade issues when upgrading CSVhelper libraries from version 2.7 to 30

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My application is using CSVHelper libraries of very old version 2.7.1.
Now I want to upgrade to the latest version of CSVHelper version 30.
I have installed using the NuGet package manager. When I build my application, it throws errors.
Below is the old code that throws an error.

```
 csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeaderRecord;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
     csvReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionCallback =
                        (ex, row) =>
                        {
                            if (ex is CsvHelper.TypeConversion.CsvTypeConverterException)
                            {
                                foreach (DictionaryEntry error in ex.Data)
                                {
                                    AddRowError(row.Row, error.Value.ToString() + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(row) + "'");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (ex is FormatException)
                            {
                                AddRowError(row.Row, ex.Message + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(row) + "' Column Value: '" + GetColumnValue(row) + "'");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AddRowError(row.Row, string.Format("Line[{0}]: {1}", row.Row, ex.StackTrace));
                            }

                        };
```

One more error about The type or namespace name 'ICsvReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone suggest how to fix these upgradation issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration must be passed in to the `CsvReader` constructor. The constructor also now requires either `CultureInfo` or `IReaderConfiguration` to be passed in with the `TextReader`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        IgnoreBlankLines = false,
        ReadingExceptionOccurred = args => { Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString()); return false;},
        MissingFieldFound = null,
        TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n1\n2,name2\nthree,name3\n4,name4"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how to modify this csvReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionCallback =

Comment: In my code I have captured Row level exceptions.

Comment: `ReadingExceptionOccurred` should do that for you.  In my example I am catching the `TypeConverterException` from trying to convert the string "three" into an `int` and writing the exception to the `Console`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. How to handle row.Row?

Comment: `args.Exception.Context.Parser.Row`

Comment: 1) How to write ex.Data? I tried as args.Exception.Data. But it didn't work. 2) ex is FormatException. for this I have tried as args.Exception.GetType() == typeof(FormatException). Is this fine?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a replacement for `ex.Data`.  It stops on the first column that throws an exception.  I don't see a way to loop through multiple `TypeConverterException`s. I don't believe it throws a `FormatException` anymore.  It looks like `DateTime` could throw the `FormatException` in the past, but now it appears to throw a `TypeConverterException`.