# Upgrade issues when upgrading CSVhelper libraries from version 2.13 to 30

Tags: c#, csv, upgrade, nuget-package, csvhelper

I am getting below errors after upgrading CsvHelper from nuget package from version 2.13.5.0 to 30.0.1

The type or namespace ICsvReaderRow could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace ICsvReader could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this ICsvReader reader, Func<ICsvReaderRow, T> selector)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return selector(reader);
        } while (reader.Read());
    }
```

Also,
How can i check reader.IsRecordEmpty() in new version
below is the old code

```
public static string GetSingleValue(this IReaderRow reader)
        {
            return reader.IsRecordEmpty() ? null : reader.Context.Parser.Record.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the [change log](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/) for CsvHelper you will find: `ICsvReader to IReader
ICsvReaderRow to IReaderRow` back in version 3.0.0.

Comment: public static string GetSingleValueByIndex(this ICsvReaderRow reader, int index)
        {
            string val = null;
            if(!reader.IsRecordEmpty() && (reader.CurrentRecord.Count() >= (index + 1)))
            {
                val = reader.CurrentRecord[index];
            }
            return val;
        } I changed it, but now it give s error for IsRecordEmpty, current record and many such properties used in above code

Comment: @Radha - please use the [edit] button to add any necessary code to the question itself.  It's almost impossible to read code in comments.  Also, is [upgrade issues when upgrading CSVhelper libraries from version 2.7 to 30](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75296812/3744182) sufficiently related to answer your question?

Comment: How can i check IsRecordEmpty() in newer version ?